# how to use Reactor3's Context in SpringCloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor, webflux

I tried to use the context to set some value of Reactor3 in the filter of SpringCloud Gateway but in the controller，I can't get the value in the Context.

Actually， I am new to Reactor3. So please give me some tips or help, thank you very much!

```
//my GatewayFilter
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

    return chain.filter(exchange)
             .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("key", "hello gate"));
}

//my Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/test")
public Mono<String> test() {

     return Mono.subscriberContext()
            .map(ctx -> ctx.get("key"));
}
```

when I try to get the value of Context , it will throw an Exception "context is empty"

Comment: Seems like yor filter is not picked by spring or it is not added in the required order. You need to share your whole filter class definition.

Answer (score 0):

`GatewayFilter` is applied to gateway-proxied routes only and will not be applied to web controllers/routes automatically.

To achieve this you could register `WebFilter` instead

```
public class TestWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(exchange)
                .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put("key", "hello gate"));
    }
}
```

ps

`subscriberContext` is deprecated. Better use `contextWrite` & `deferContextual`.